# How can I get the ID of a user who deletes a channel?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
Client.on("channelCreate", channel => {
    if(protection){
        channel.delete()
    }
})
Client.on("channelDelete", channel => {
    if(protection){
        channel.client. (don't want to create channel the bot have delete)
    }
})
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only realistic way of achieving this would be fetching the audit logs, as seen below.

```js
client.on('channelDelete', async channel => {
  const fetched = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 'CHANNEL_DELETE' })
  console.log(fetched.entries.first().executor.id)
})
```

Comment: I have an error when I do that
`  if(fetched.entries.first().executor.id != Client.user.id){
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
`